# AWS api gateway - http proxy should take status code from origin

Tags: http-proxy, aws-api-gateway

I am currently trying to setup AWS Api Gateway, to proxy to another api, that has fully functional methods, response content, status codes etc. This is fairly simple to setup, but I have noticed that the Api Gateway always returns `200 OK` no matter what the origin api responds with.

Fx. if there was a bad request (in the origin api) which results in a error message in `JSON` and a `400 Bad Request`, the Api Gateway will respond with a the exact same error message, but a status code of `200 OK`

If I remove all settings from the `Message Response` in the API Gateway web-interface, I get an internal error in the API Gateway. Can it be true that I have to map all the different status codes from the origin api manually in the Api Gateway?

I would prefer if it was possible to just let the status code (as well as the response, which currently works great) pass through, and not have the Api Gateway touch it in any way.

Answer (score 1):

Proxy integration can be used to achieve this. In this case, it is HTTP Proxy. Lambda Proxy integration can also be used but will need some code logic in lambda. API GW will then return the result as-is.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that currently when using API Gateway you are required to map all response codes in your integration responses. We have heard this "pass through" request from other customers and we may consider including this in future updates to the service.